# How to get the owning publication of a component via the Core Service?

Tags: 2013, core-service

Probably I am missing something obvious, but I can't see how to find out the owning repository (ie the publication where a component is created) when I have opened a component with the Core Service... `ComponentData.LocationInfo` only has `ContextRepository`, which I guess is the publication which I opened the component in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either `ComponentData.BluePrintInfo.OwningRepository` or `ComponentData.BluePrintInfo.PrimaryBluePrintParentItem` is what you are looking for, depending on whether you need the parent of the item or the item in the top of the BluePrint chain where it was created in.

Comment: Thanks Bart - I also see PrimaryBluePrintParentItem - I guess this is the *real* parent, and OwningRepository can be the place where the item has been localized between its parent and context publications... right?

Comment: @WillPrice Yup that is my understanding too, so you might indeed need `ComponentData.BluePrintInfo.PrimaryBluePrintParentItem`