# Getting the root Parent Publication using Tom API

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, publishing, event-system, tom.net

I need to get the parent root publication (a publication which is at the topmost in the hierachy) from a specific child publication at any level in the hierarchy. I need to use TOM API and not core service. Could somebody please help me in achieving it with the best way?

We are using Tridion 2013.

Comment: Get current publication .Parent collection, until the current publication has no parents? I'm sure there's a much nicer way to do this, but you are in a hurry :)

Comment: food for thought: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4681/how-to-retrieve-parent-component-object-from-a-localized-component-using-tom-net

Comment: I need the most optimized way please (want to avoid looping through the parents).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks All. I got solution to my issue using the following approach:

```
SystemManager manager = Session.SystemManager;
BluePrintParentsFilter  bluePrintParentFilter = new BluePrintParentsFilte(Session)
{
 ForRepository = publication
};

IEnumerable<Repository> bluePrintParents = manager.GetBluePrintParents(bluePrintParentsFilter);
```

and then iterating through the collection to check the Parents count. If count is 0 then just come out of the iteration with the root publication.